# electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism

I came across this problem, and I am having a difficult time to understand the direction of E. why the final answer is in -z and y direction?, when I do the cross product I get -z and 
-y direction. I think I missing something here. The negative sign in front of the intrinsic impedance is throwing me off here.  Can anyone help me out ? 
 [image]

Comment: Why did you post one question twice? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/192398/e-and-h-relationship/192409#192409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the direction of axb (where a and b are vectors, of course ) we may use right hand rule (see image)  in which forefinger represents direction of a, middlefinger represents direction of b(second vector in product)  and the thumb represents the direction of product vector axb.
Using this you must understand that z cross x is y but x cross z is -y. When you get this you won't find next step  difficult to understand which just does - (z-y) = (-z+y).

Don't forget to use only the right hand not the left.
Don't make wrong xyz coordinate axes (in which the x y z choosen by you are themselves not following x cross y equal to z).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is in the -100 (+z-y) you are having difficulty. The 100 negates the millivolts to get -1(z-y) while if you multiply the -1*z and the -1*-y you end up with (y-z) or (-z+y).

Comment: why x cross z is -y?

Comment: It's not. I just rearranged the order. -1 times +z = -z and -1 times -y = +y. hence result is (-z+y)

Comment: but negative sign outside the bracket will change z and y to -z and -y, why the final answer is one negative and one positive? I don't understand this

Comment: Ahh  ok. I see your issue. Consider this.... -1*(z-y) is the same as -1*((+z)+(-y)) so if you expand that out you get (-1*(+z) + -1*(-y)) and further ((-z)+(+y)) which finally becomes  (-z+y)

Comment: oh wait. no now I see it you are referring to the second line. Sorry I'm not familar with that formula so I can't explain the -y20 or z10....